# Add new item to <p> tag and assign to drop down list dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing a website that allow user to add new group to the existing group. In the existing group it already have three fixed group which are `It, cleaning, accountant`, so my idea was letting user to add group name by clicking `submit` and their input field will be sent to
empty's `<p>` tag (eg： nurse, doctor.. and so on differentiate which a coma `,`). Other than that, after I able to get the  existing and new added group, I need to dynamically add the full groups to a drop down list. `(eg: It, cleaning, accountant, nurse, doctor)`.

I know stackoverflow is not a code writing service, but I do make own research before posting this question and I couldn't found any useful resources. So anyone who willing to guide me will be much appreciate. Thanks in advance

**Current template:**

[image]

**Expected Output:**

[image]

Full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <h1>Existing Group</h1>
      <p>IT, Cleaning, Accountant</p>
      <h1>Add New Group</h1>
      <p></p>
      <input type="tel" id="group" name="group" placeholder="enter group name">
      <br><br>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Submit</button>
      <h1>Drop Down List</h1>
      <label for="group">Choose a group:</label>
      <select name="group" id="group">
         <option value="IT">IT</option>
         <option value="Cleaning">Cleaning</option>
         <option value="Accountant">Accountant</option>
      </select>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think what you are looking for is DOM basics with JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents#creating_and_placing_new_nodes
These techniques allow you to add/change/delete elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use JavaScript.

First, you use `addEventListener()` to listen when the user clicks the submit button. Then, we get the value of the input and separate it by commas with `input.value.split(',')`. Then, we loop through the values, create a new `<option>` tag and add it to the `<select>` tag.

Also, you have two elements with `id="group"`, so you need to change one of them. I changed the `<select>` to `id="group-select"`.

```js
const submit = document.querySelector('button');
const input  = document.querySelector('input');
const select = document.querySelector('select');
const myP    = document.querySelector('p#myP');

submit.addEventListener('click', function(e)
{
  const values = input.value.split(',');
  
  if (myP.innerText == '')
  {
    myP.innerText = values;
  }
  else
  {
    myP.innerText += ', ' + values;
  }
  
  for (let i in values)
  {
    const new_option = document.createElement('option');
    
    new_option.value     = values[i];
    new_option.innerText = values[i];
    
    select.appendChild(new_option);
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <h1>Existing Group</h1>
      <p>IT, Cleaning, Accountant</p>
      <h1>Add New Group</h1>
      <p id="myP"></p>
      <input type="tel" id="group" name="group" placeholder="enter group name">
      <br><br>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Submit</button>
      <h1>Drop Down List</h1>
      <label for="group">Choose a group:</label>
      <select name="group" id="group-select">
         <option value="IT">IT</option>
         <option value="Cleaning">Cleaning</option>
         <option value="Accountant">Accountant</option>
      </select>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response , this is very close to my result but I need the user input to be continue and not overwrited. For example: first input is `Nurse` then when user second input is `Doctor` it will become `Nurse, Doctor` and not just the latest `Doctor`

Comment: @terry5546 Ok, it should work now

Comment: Very thanks for your help ! , Actually i do need to find a way to delete user input as well. But anyhow i will figure it out myself. Thanks again Luis !

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you will need to use some javascript depending on your requirements to add the extra node as follows:

**Pure JS:**

```
   var result = document.getElementById("group");
   var tag = document.createElement("option");
   tag.setAttribute("value",result.value)
   var text = document.createTextNode(result.value);
   tag.appendChild(text);
   var element = document.getElementById("groupSelect");
   element.appendChild(tag);
```

Keep in mind you have 2 elements with the same ID (group), which will cause most of your JS to crash. Also note that you can also use Jquery which might be a bit easier as well

Comment: Thanks for ur quick response, but how can i implement this method to my full code? I tried to put these code to the `submit` onclick function but nothing worked .